# Webmin Java applets not starting

Tags: linux, linux-mint, java-applet, webmin

I have running Mint 13 (based on Ubuntu 12.04) KDE desktop with Firefox 19.0.2 and Opera 12.14 browsers. Java installed default by the system and its version is:

> $~/ java -version
>
> java version "1.7.0_15"
>
> OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea7 2.3.7) (7u15-2.3.7-0ubuntu1~12.04.1)
>
> OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.7-b01, mixed mode)

Java test page (`http://www.java.com/en/download/testjava.jsp`) displays like this:

[image: Java.com Test Page]

And each browser have IcedTea7 Plugin for run java apples. But Webmin applets not working with this configuration. All browsers says `applet not initialized` when I try to open an applet included Webmin page.

I have no clue why webmin applets not working.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the reason but they've updated java yet again for another security issue to update 17 which may have caused mint or firefox to disable java until you update

Comment: That image just show only IcedTea Java plug-in works fine. As I mentioned above system has installed OpenJDK and Iced Tea. Not Oracle Java SE. Java test page brings wrong results.

Comment: I get that but if Firefox thinks it's out of date it will block it I don't know about opera.

Comment: Nope... Firefox doesn't thinks it's outdated. It's not blocked in my Firefox plug-ins. Also if it was blocked, I must get an "outdated" error while browsing to java test page.